# Individual Share Url - Routing Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have a custom shareable URL for every user in my app. This URL allows a user to share the Site and credits them for conversion.
My issue is, that when I try to catch this route, I run into the problem that all of my Urls - even the non-shared ones are being considered as user-share-urls.

I understand this is happening because how I have set up my routes.rb

#### routes.rb

```
match '/:in_url' => 'share_links#go'
```

#### ShareLinksController.rb

```
def go
  if @link = Spree::ShareLink.find_by_in_url(params[:in_url])
    session[:converter] = @link.user_id
    redirect_to root_path, :status => @link.http_status
  end
end
```

How would I set up this, so either only the shareable urls are being processed by the controller - or if the @link is nil, I would just go on with the regular request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this route at the end of your routes file and see if the problem persists.

Not sure how your app is set up but what happens when users make a typo? Maybe change it to something like:

```
def go
  if @link = Spree::ShareLink.find_by_in_url(params[:in_url])
    session[:converter] = @link.user_id
    redirect_to root_path, :status => @link.http_status
  else
    redirect_to root_path # or 404 page
  end
end
```